# Check if a JavaScript object has already been instantiated

Tags: javascript, object

I'm developing a small game and I instantiate a few objects like this :

```
this.polyfills = new Application.Polyfills(this.options);
```

The thing is that that piece of code it's called a bunch of times on click ( of some element on the page ) and I would like not to instantiate that object each time as it already did it's purpose. I have tried something like this :

```
this.polyfills = window.Application.Polyfills || new Application.Polyfills(this.options);
```

But the above obviously doesn't work :) So what would be the way to go and do what I just described ?

**EDIT :** The object ( I call it a class ) that is instantiated on click is this one :

```
Application.Level = function(_level, _levels, callback) {

    this.helpers = (this.helpers instanceof Application.Helpers) ? true : new Application.Helpers();

    var self = this,

        _options = {
            levels : {
                count : _levels,
                settings : (_level === undefined || _level === '') ? null : self.setLevelSettings(_level, _levels),
                template : 'templates/levels.php'
            },

            api : {
                getImages : {
                    service : 'api/get-images.php',
                    directory : 'assets/img/'
                }
            }
        };

    this.options = new Application.Defaults(_options);
    this.polyfills = (this.polyfills instanceof Application.Polyfills) ? true : new Application.Polyfills(this.options);

    return this.getImages(self.options.api.getImages.service, { url : self.options.api.getImages.directory }, function(data){
        return (typeof callback === 'function' && callback !== undefined) ? callback.apply( callback, [ data, self.options, self.helpers ] ) : 'Argument : Invalid [ Function Required ]';
    });
};
```

Which contains a collection on properties defined through the `prototype`. So what I'm trying to do might not be possible ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use instanceof:

```
this.polyfills = this.polyfills instanceof Application.Polyfills ? this.polyfills : new Application.Polyfills(this.options)
```

This will verify that it's not just an object, but that it's an Application.Polyfills instantiation.

Comment: I tried this one, but apparently every time I click I create a new instance of that object. I was thinking that I could somehow check globally if that object was instantiated ?!

Comment: What is "this" in your context? If that changes then it will cause another instantiation. If you want to make sure it's not instantiated more than once, you could put that if in your constructor and make polyfills a global and make the constructor return the polyfills variable.

Answer (score 9):

What about ?

```
this.polyfills = this.polyfills || new Application.Polyfills(this.options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something as simple as :

```js
if(typeof myClass.prototype === "undefined") {
   // the class is instanciated
}
```

Please check [this pen](https://codepen.io/seb-rom-o/pen/eYZYyYO?editors=0012) to see a working example.

I like it because it does not rely on the context of the call.